# Can't connect to MS Windows share after switching to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, samba

In 8.04, 9.04, 10.04 and 11.04 I have been able to connect to a Windows 2003 server.  It has been simple and effective.

Since loading 12.04, I can't do it.  The error highlights the password (which works on the 11.04 laptop beside it).  In fact, no password is acceptable.

I have tried it with Ubuntu and Xubuntu 12.04 with the same result.

Likewise, the answers posted with "[Cannot connect to Samba share from Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50197/cannot-connect-to-samba-share-from-nautilus)" have not resolved the issue.

Comment: While I am *not* saying this question should be interpreted as an attempt to report a bug and closed as off-topic, if a bug hasn't been reported for this, [it should be](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), since it worked with previous versions of Ubuntu but stopped working in 12.04. [travis's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/134532/22949) may provide some insight into reporting the bug (assuming that works for you).

Answer (score 7):

I was having this same issue.  I got it to work by entering the domain with all capital letters.  Never have I had to do that before.

Comment: I've been trying for the last couple hours to get my shares to work until I ran into this. When did Windows become case sensitive. Ugh!

Answer (score 4):

I got this answer in a different thread, and it works perfectly.

In `/etc/samba/smb.conf` add the following to the bottom of the `[global]` section:

```
client lanman auth = yes 
client ntlmv2 auth = no
```

Comment: You've posted what is essentially this answer, in three places. Can you edit your answers to include a link to the source of this information?

Comment: The all-caps solution did not work for me, but this did. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'm WAY late upgrading. I spent hours trying to find a solution and this is the one that finally worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then I enter the UNC share location in the form: `smb://server-name/sharename` or `smb://servername/c$` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I'm then presented with a login box, where I enter the windows username, the domain name and the windows password. Tip: I change `/etc/samba/smb.conf`'s `"WORKGROUP"` to the domain name so it automatically populates in the login box.

Perhaps you could check to ensure samba-common is installed?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install samba-common
```

Also, maybe your domain uses some funky authentication settings in `` `/etc/samba/smb.conf ``.