# How to enable Nautilus in Ubuntu 18.04 to share a folder?

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba

To share a folder in Nautilus, I have first installed samba via

```
sudo apt install samba
```

Next, I had also used `synaptic` to install `nautilus-share` (a Nautilus extension to share folder using Samba).

Thereafter, in nautilus, I have used the mouse to right-clicked on the folder that I had wanted to share. However, I could not see the `Local Network Share` option there. Neither do I see a `Local Network Share` tab after clicking on `Properties`.

How do I enable nautilus to share a folder?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/323441/541417).

So after performing those installation steps mentioned in my question, I next had to type the following commands in the terminal.

First, quit `nautilus`:

```
$ nautilus -q
```

Next, restart nautilus:

```
$ nautilus
```

Thereafter, whenever I right-clicked a folder in Nautilus, the `Local Network Share` option appears.